# How to document the structure type info in doxygen index.xml file

Tags: structure, doxygen

I defined a structure MY_STRUCTURE using typdef in .h file and created an instance MY_STRUCTURE MyStruct in .c file. I use Doxygen to output xml file.

My question is in the index.xml file, it only shows the structure instance name without showing its type.

```
<member refid="d6/d68/test_8c_1a89a9f154447f0a42e64c961660b4dd34" kind="variable"><name>MyStruct</name></member>
```

Without this info, I cannot link the structure instance name "MyStruct" with its type "MY_STRUCTURE".

Does anyone know how to link these two info in the output xml file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any option to add that info to the index file, so I don't think that is possible. You can however look up the type using the refid.

So given a member definition:

```
<member refid="main_8c_1ad514631b0d3cf856a07ef28509ad007a" kind="variable"><name>testStruct</name></member>
```

You can lookup in the file main_8c.xml(Should be `d6/d86/test_8c.xml` for you) the memberdef by matching id:

```
  <sectiondef kind="var">
  <memberdef kind="variable" id="main_8c_1ad514631b0d3cf856a07ef28509ad007a" prot="public" static="no" mutable="no">
    <type><ref refid="structMY__STRUCTURE" kindref="compound">MY_STRUCTURE</ref></type>
    <definition>MY_STRUCTURE testStruct</definition>
```